# 'friendly urls' is it a good approach for this matter?

Tags: asp.net, friendly-url

I am working on a website that is set to display students’ profiles. I got almost everything up and running. Right now the profiles are accessible through an individual page for each profile. I have static HTML page for each student, something like:

- http://mywebsite/stories/Student_name1.aspx
- http://mywebsite/stories/Student_name2.aspx

I am moving profiles’ data to a database so that I can safe time and space where I don’t have to create page for each profile, because all profiles share almost the same template. I will just pull profile’s data by profileID (very basic approach)

- http://mywebsite/stories/story.aspx?Id=1
- http://mywebsite/stories/story.aspx?Id=2

My question is; I want a more readable url. What approaches I can follow to get something like (no .aspx at the end)

- http://mywebsite/stories/Student_name1
- http://mywebsite/stories/student_name2

Note that I still want to get profiles’ data from database using only one page. I am thinking of friendly urls but have no clue how to approach this. 
The only think I could think of is an MVC app and then create action for each student, where the action is the name of that student. Unfortunately, my application is a normal ASP.net web forms.

Comment: I don't know how much of an explanation you need, but yes, that seems like a reasonable time to use them. There are tutorials around, but basically what you'll be looking for is `http://mywebsite/stories/Student_name/1` where `Student_name.aspx` is your file, then you'll ask Friendly Urls for the first argument, which is `1`.

Comment: [This should help](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/using-friendly-urls-in-web-forms) - and end up with something like `/stories/1`

Comment: Alright, I am looking at this now

Comment: The thing EdSF posted is great for Web Forms, I've used it myself. [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx) has a nice blog entry about it. But the more you go down that route, the more you start thinking about ASP.NET MVC and how the routing there would make things a lot easier. That's how I eventually made the jump to MVC.

Comment: I will go with `/stories/{student-name}` where `student-name` is a `string` where I will filter my data based on that string. Don't worry about misspelled `studnetname`(s) because I will be pulling their names from the database before generating urls for their profiles. @EdSF Please create an answer that has your commend so I can mark it as correct answer. Thank you guys.

Comment: No need - its a comment really - for you to look into, tinker/work with :) You can mark your own question as answered. Best ~

Comment: Any ideas why the following good is not passing the querystring to the page `routes.MapPageRoute("student", "Stories/{profilename}", "~/Stories/StoryTeller.aspx");`. My url is `http://localhost:56273/Stories/TylerYarde`, while the `this.Request.QueryString["profilename"];` returns `null` and the array's count is `0`. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: `this.Page.RouteData.Values["profilename"].ToString();` instead of `this.Request.QueryString["profilename"];`
http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/routing-in-asp-net-4-0-web-forms